# map-indexed alternative for reducers

Tags: clojure

Is there a `map-indexed` alternative for clojure.core.reducers? I would like something that would work lazily like `r/map` (without constructing new sequence).

Comment: if you're not bound to reducers only, you can use transducer version of `map-indexed`, that would allow you avoid creating intermediate collections

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that what you really want to use is a [transducer](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers), since `map-indexed` has a 1-arity version (as does `map`, `filter`, and many other core functions) that returns a transducer.  Transducers are composable, and do not create an intermediate sequence.  Here is a short example:

```
(def xf (comp
          (map-indexed (fn [i value] [i value]))
          (filter (fn [[i value]] (odd? i)))
          (map second)))
```

This says:  generate an indexed vector using `map-indexed`, filter out only the vectors whose index is odd, and get the second element.  It's a long-winded way of saying `(filter odd? collection)` but it's only for example purposes.

You can use this with `into`:

```
(into [] xf "ThisIsATest")
=> [\h \s \s \T \s]
```

or you can use the `transduce` function and apply `str` to the result:

```
(transduce xf str "ThisIsATest")
=> "hssTs"
```

Comment: Nice, clean and simple. Also should be tagged as a "Transducer De-Mystifier" example.

Comment: This isn't actually `(filter odd? coll)` at all, because you are filtering on the index, not the value. Rather, it's `(take-nth 2 (rest coll))`.